# Dynamic counter with fixed strings using setText()?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement a method for counting the number of clicks on the button.  The method returns a string "Сlicked X times". X is the number of clicks. After the first click it returns a TextView-message "clicked 1 times".  The second click closes the application. Error: NumberFormatException  for input string "checked 1 times". How to make the dynamical update of the number with strings?  Without strings "checked" and "times" it increases the number correctly.

```
private void counterMethod(View v) {

            String countValue = numberOfClicks.getText().toString();
            int intCountValue = Integer.parseInt(countValue);

            intCountValue++;
            String stringCountValue=String.valueOf(intCountValue);

           numberOfClicks.setText("checked "+stringCountValue +" times");

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all non numeric chars from the string with `replaceAll()` before parsing it:

```
String countValue = numberOfClicks.getText().toString();
if (countValue.trim().length() == 0) countValue = "0";
int intCountValue = Integer.parseInt(countValue.replaceAll("\\D", ""));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works!  String countValue = numberOfClicks.getText().toString().replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");

Comment: Check my edit for the case the textview is empty, if there is such a case.

Comment: Your edit does not work  if the textview is empty. It must be empty before the first click has been done. Logically. But now the counter does not increase the number. I do not understand why....The first solution worked with the TextView having "0".

Comment: If the textview is empty then the if statement will make `countValue = "0"` and the parsing will make `int intCountValue =0` so `intCountValue++;` will make `intCountValue =1`. So what doesn't work?

Comment: I deleted "intCountValue++"...My mistake.  Now it works perfectly! Thanks a lot!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?:

```
numberOfClicks.setText("checked $intCountValue times");
```

Comment: It does not work unfortunately.... It return "checked $intCountValue times" after the 1st click.

Answer (score 0):

The second click closes the application because during the second click `countValue` will be holding a non-integer String.

```
String countValue = numberOfClicks.getText().toString();

// the above variable will be holding the string "checked 1 times"
// When parsing this to Integer, the application throws an error in 
// the following line.

int intCountValue = Integer.parseInt("checked 1 times");
```

To solve this, you have to keep the count seperately and not fetch it from the Text field.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) The method .replaceAll("[^\\d.]" helped me.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this :

````
int intCountValue =0;

private void counterMethod(View v) {

    intCountValue++;
    numberOfClicks.setText("checked "+intCountValue +" times");         


        }```
````

Comment: numberOfClicks is my TextView. It contained "0".  But I need a solution for the case if the TextView is empty.  Using the method getText() I get the value from the TextView.   Your "intCountValue" is not linked with the TextView. It won't work.